# Image doesn't send for other side Android Studio java

Tags: java, image, android-studio

I have problem, because I can't send images for other side, it duplicates or sends empty message, but normal messages work fine.
I've tried many tutorials and changing some classes, but nothing really worked

here's my recycler view class:

```
public final class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<ChatMessage> messages;
    private Bitmap profileImage;
    private final String senderId;

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_SENT = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED = 2;

    public void setReceiverProfileImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.profileImage = bitmap;
    }

    public ChatAdapter(List<ChatMessage> messages, Bitmap profileImage, String senderId) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_SENT ? new SentMessageViewHolder(
                ItemContainerSentMessageBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        parent,
                        false)
        ) : new ReceivedMessageViewHolder(
                ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        parent,
                        false)
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_SENT) {
            ((SentMessageViewHolder) holder).setData(messages.get(position));
        } else {
            ((ReceivedMessageViewHolder) holder).setData(messages.get(position), profileImage);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (messages.get(position).getSenderId().equals(senderId) ? VIEW_TYPE_SENT : VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED);
    }

    public static class SentMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ItemContainerSentMessageBinding binding;

        public SentMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerSentMessageBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void setData(ChatMessage message) {
            binding.textMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            binding.textDateTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
            binding.image.setImageBitmap(message.getImage());
        }
    }

    public static class ReceivedMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding binding;

        public ReceivedMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void setData(ChatMessage message, Bitmap bitmap) {
            binding.textMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            binding.textDateTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
            if (bitmap != null) {
                binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            binding.image.setImageBitmap(message.getImage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's received message:

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textMessage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:riv_oval="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_received_message"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageProfile"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="@drawable/background_sent_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:maxHeight="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageProfile"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDateTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textMessage"/>
```

and picking image activity:

```
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImage = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() != RESULT_OK) return;
        if (result.getData() == null) return;
        Uri imageUri = result.getData().getData();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            this.encodingImage = encodeImage(bitmap);
            sendMessage();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

and here create ChatMessage object (eventListener):

```
    private final EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = (value, error) -> {
        if (error != null) {
            return;
        }
        if (value != null) {
            int count = messages.size();
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(
                            documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID),
                            documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID),
                            documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE),
                            getReadableDateTime(documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP)),
                            documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP)
                    );
                    if (!encodingImage.isEmpty()) {
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodingImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        chatMessage.setImage(decodedByte);
                    }
                    messages.add(chatMessage);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(messages, Comparator.comparing(ChatMessage::getDate));
            if (count == 0) {
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                chatAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(messages.size(), messages.size());
                binding.chatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
            }
            binding.chatRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (conversionId == null) checkForConversion();
    };
```

sendMessage method:

```
    private void sendMessage() {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
        message.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, user.getId());
        message.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        if (!encodingImage.isEmpty()) {
            message.put(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_MESSAGE, encodingImage);
        }
        message.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date());
        db.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT).add(message);
        if (conversionId != null) {
            updateConversion(binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        } else {
            Map<String, Object> conversion = new HashMap<>();
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_IMAGE, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE));

            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, user.getId());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_NAME, user.getName());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_IMAGE, user.getImage());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date());
            addConversion(conversion);
        }
        if (!isReceiverAvaible) {
            try {
                JSONArray tokens = new JSONArray();
                tokens.put(user.getToken());

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put(Constants.KEY_USER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());

                JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
                body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_DATA, data);
                body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_REGISTRATION_IDS, tokens);

                sendNotification(body.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        binding.inputMessage.setText(null);
    }
```

listenMessages method:

```
    private void listenMessages() {
        db.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID))
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, user.getId())
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
        db.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, user.getId())
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID))
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
    }
```

```
    private String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int previewWidth = 300;
        int previewHeight = bitmap.getHeight() * previewWidth / bitmap.getWidth();
        Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, previewWidth, previewHeight, false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

**Please help and thanks!**

Comment: pls share your `sendMessage()` method. Even I have followed the tutorial u r following. According to that, in the method u r getting the message from the edit text and then sending it. But, here I see that your are not setting the image bitmap to the edit text.

Comment: and by `Image doesn't send for other side` do you mean that the image is seen of the sender's device but not on the receiver's?

Comment: yes, so it shows on sender's side but not on receiver's

Comment: this shows that the image is not correctly decoded

Comment: in the `ChatMessage` object, are you verifying that the `encodedImage` is empty or not?

Comment: no, I'm checking it in adapter class

Comment: so it not empty right? Try logging the base 64 string and then check if it is valid on [this](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) website.

Comment: it's correct, but in ReceivedMessageViewHolder class the ChatMessage#getImage is null and I have no idea why

Comment: please provide the `listenMessages` method

Comment: done, but I don't think so it will help you

Comment: Sorry. I meant that event listener for  it

Comment: okay done, I hope it will help

Comment: Where are you setting the variable `encodingImage`?

Comment: it's field, and I'm setting it in choosing picture method, do you need it?

Comment: Aha! Got it. Found the issue. I will answer tomorrow.  Ok,

Comment: ok, and thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

---

You are actually providing the adapter the `encodingImage` which was just created and that is why you get repeated or no image at all.

### The solution

There are 2 parts in this solution:

1. Reformat the methods and their parameters
2. Change the code to pick image for sending image

Let's start !

##### 1. Reformat the methods and their parameters

First of all, you need to add 1 parameter to the `sendMessage()` method. It will look something like this:

```java
private void sendMessage(String encodedImage) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
        message.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, user.getId());
        message.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        message.put(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_MESSAGE, encodedImage);
        message.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date());
        db.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT).add(message);
        if (conversionId != null) {
            updateConversion(binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        } else {
            Map<String, Object> conversion = new HashMap<>();
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_IMAGE, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE));

            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID, user.getId());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_NAME, user.getName());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_IMAGE, user.getImage());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP, new Date());
            addConversion(conversion);
        }
        if (!isReceiverAvaible) {
            try {
                JSONArray tokens = new JSONArray();
                tokens.put(user.getToken());

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put(Constants.KEY_USER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN, preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN));
                data.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE, binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());

                JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
                body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_DATA, data);
                body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_REGISTRATION_IDS, tokens);

                sendNotification(body.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        binding.inputMessage.setText(null);
    }
```

Now after this, you need to change the `eventListener` object. It will look like this:

```java
private final EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = (value, error) -> {
        if (error != null) {
            return;
        }
        if (value != null) {
            int count = messages.size();
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(
                            documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID),
                            documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID),
                            documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE),
                            getReadableDateTime(documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP)),
                            documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP)
                    );
                    if (documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_MESSAGE) != null && !documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_MESSAGE).isEmpty()) {
                        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode((documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE_MESSAGE, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        chatMessage.setImage(decodedByte);
                    }
                    messages.add(chatMessage);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(messages, Comparator.comparing(ChatMessage::getDate));
            if (count == 0) {
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                chatAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(messages.size(), messages.size());
                binding.chatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
            }
            binding.chatRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (conversionId == null) checkForConversion();
    };
```

---

##### 2. Change the code to pick image for sending image

Now you are doing a very very wrong thing while trying to send an image method. This issue start's from the place where you are picking the image. To solve it, replace that with this code:

```java
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImage = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() != RESULT_OK) return;
        if (result.getData() == null) return;
        Uri imageUri = result.getData().getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            sendMessage(encodeImage(bitmap));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Also you need to change the `encodeImage` method now!:

```java
private String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int previewWidth = 300;
        int previewHeight = bitmap.getHeight() * previewWidth / bitmap.getWidth();
        Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, previewWidth, previewHeight, false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String str = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return str == null ? "" : str;
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243310/discussion-on-answer-by-sambhav-khandelwal-image-doesnt-send-for-other-side-and).